# View Tiff Image On Mobile Devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want To View Tiff Image On Mobile Devices Using Jquery Mobile. As U know Tiff Images Cant be Viewed on mobile devices and browsers we have to decode/convert it into jpeg image file format. I have been able to do this in android(using java and NDK). Now i want to do the same thing in jquery- Mobile so that It becomes Platform Independent For ios, android and windows.
Efforts Will Be Highly Appreciated..  Thanks

Comment: Whether or not you can do this with javascript, you shouldn't. You should convert it server side.

Comment: Yeah, just convert dem TIFFs to JPEG, and display those.

Comment: @ Andy Ray I don't want to do it on server side as it can overload/reduce capacity of the server. Better U give/tell me the way to do this with javascript if u know.